# How to remove the BIOS password using Ubuntu?

Tags: 10.04

i want to remove a power on password on laptop lenovo g550 using ubuntu version 10.04.1.

Possibly I'm looking for a way to flash the BIOS to remove the password from Ubuntu.

Instead of flashing the BIOS I've tried removing the cmos batt for at least one hour and pack all up just thinking it will be erased automatically but in vain.

i am thinking that it is stored in the eeprom but i cant remove it or be able to read the password.

i tried to bypass the bios password but that too in vain.... does someone on earth have any ubuntu solution for it pls???

Comment: http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-3000-and-Essential/G550-is-it-possible-to-reset-bios-password/td-p/183018 See page 34 of your manual. Suggesting to close as off topic.

Answer (score 2):

Power on password is not related to the OS that is installed on your laptop nor on its version.
If you know the admin password for your laptop you should also be able to remove it by setting it to blank password in the BIOS configuration screen (after turning on, see the onscreen message about which button to press to enter the configuration menu).

Answer (score 1):

In desktop computers there is a jumper for quick reset for bios, I think laptops do not include such thing, Use your laptop vendors web site, or manual to learn more about password recovery