# Clearing BIOS Administrator Password/password

Tags: boot

After a clean install of Windows 10, my [HP 17-ca1003ds laptop](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c05985614) won't boot to the installed OS. When I try to change the boot order it requires a password that I didn't put in it. It is not asking for an administrator password!  And it is Not locked out. I am Not asking for you or anyone else to tell me or help me get around or crack a password!

After clicking on troubleshoot, then selecting UEFI in order to get to the boot order and change it to USB or asks for a password.  (?). Selecting that "choose a different device" (to boot from) box...it returns with device. failed. If I use F8 menu is no good because if I'm not wrong it's used IF there is either the the optical or USB is going to be used for booting. I will of course try F8 when I get the installation.
BUT..
I'm thinking of just formatting the entire drive (SSD) And do what I should have done years ago and go to Ubuntu/Linux (not sure of what flavor yet) 
Am I still going to be plagued with this password issue when I do the installation process?
Also, does the installation media (I'd prefer a USB) used to install Ubuntu "capture" (for lack of a better word) the boot order thus making the computer boot from it?
The computer is a HP Model 17-ca1003ds.
The mother board is: SPS L 46459-601. The product ID# 7TY07UA#ABA. If you need more information like the SSD # I have that.

Comment: K7AAY, I'm former KB4BIL ok I have a lot of screen shots. I've followed all of the paths that I know. I guess I'll start with the F11 path.  It works is the good news.

Comment: What is the make and model of the PC? If it is custom-built, the make and model of the motherboard; if not, get the model part number from the serial number sticker. How, specifically, did you try to change the boot order? Starting from when you turn the PC on, what do you click, what do you select, what do you type, exactly? Asking because you may be hitting a password in the BIOS/Firmware Setup, and the requested info will confirm that.

Comment: It's just a normal computer HP model 17-ca1003ds. I could just buy a new SSD. Would I still have the password things going on. Parts number? Main board?

Comment: I updated the post with hopefully has the information you (or anyone) need(s,)to advise

Comment: Your HW manual is at http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c05985614 and adding another new or used drive will not solve a BIOS problem; you must solve that first. A) Turn on or restart the computer and quickly press {F10} – or – B) Turn on or restart the PC, quickly press {esc}, and then press {F10} when the Start menu is displayed as per that manual. You must clear the BIOS password before you can proceed to a solution.

Comment: Tried to move to chat, it wont let me. K7ZAAY, PRESSING F10resilts in it asking me for an Administrator password. Regardless of how I get there I used both methods you mentioned

Comment: Then the issue is not that you need to format a drive before installation. The Administrator password of the BIOS has been set and must be cleared. I'd suggest you amend the title of the question accordingly, then contact https://support.hp.com/us-en use their Chat support, and ask how to reset the BIOS Administrator password as there's nothing in the hardware manual to explain how. OBTW, you'll need 20 reputation to use Chat; reputation grows by positive actions: See https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18993/how-do-i-get-points-if-i-cant-answer-or-comment-or-vote-on-anything

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the BIOS password using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111442/how-to-remove-the-bios-password-using-ubuntu)

Comment: Thank you.  HP, has told me they no longer rest, or provide Any information on how to reset ANY password! They require buying a new main board, 300.00.im at the end of my rope! This is ridiculous. Appreciate your time sir@

Answer (score 0):

We've diagnosed the problem, and just need a solution.

Do you have another PC which will woth with the M.2 NVMe SSD from the laptop? If so,

1) Download Ubuntu's ISO file at https://ubuntu.com/download or for a supported 'flavour' with a different Desktop go to https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours

2) Check for download errors per https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0

3) Follow these instructions on a Windows PC to make make a LiveUSB https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 or on another Linux PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0

4) Remove the SSD from the laptop

5) attach it as the main drive on that other PC

6) install Ubuntu following https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0 except

7) When you get to **6 Allocate Drive Space** https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#6-allocate-drive-space choose **Install alongside Windows** which will shrink the Windows partition, give you room for Ubuntu, and install Ubuntu there.

8) When install completes, reboot and Ubuntu starts.

9) Shut down, then remove the SSD from the laptop, put the original drive back in the alternate PC, put the SSD back in the Laptop, and you now have a laptop which boots either Ubuntu or Windows.

Any competent PC shop can do this for you if the instructions seem overwhelming.

Comment: Yes I'll have to take it somewhere. Thank you.

Comment: You may wish to click on the up arrowhead if the information was useful. You may also wish to in addition, click on the checkmark to show the problem was resolved by content in the best provided answer.

Comment: I put it in the trash can after beating it with a hammer

Comment: I see no up arrow, I see no check mark...I'm on an Android,  this is definitely not optimized for cell phones. I'd be more than happy to do it. In fact I Want to do it...